# Sublime Text 3 emmet digit precision

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, emmet

emmet haves great feature called evaluate math expression
http://docs.emmet.io/actions/evaluate-math/
Unfortunately it haves 2 decimal digits precission. I would like to have at least 4.
Is there a simple solution to change it? I need solution that will be update proof.